# In a Euclidean ring $R$, prove $(a) ⊆ (b) \iff b|a$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> Let $a, b$ be elements of a Euclidean ring $R$. Prove that $$(a) \subseteq (b) \iff b \;\text{divides}\;a.$$

I have no clue how to even start this. Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: Start by analyzing the predicates "$x\in (b)$" and "$b\mid w$".

Comment: Hint: Show  $a\in (b)$ iff $b\mid a.$

Comment: If $b|a$ then $a=bk$ for some $k \in R$ hence $a \in (b)$ and so $(a) \subset (b)$. Now, if $(a)\subset (b)$, then consider $a=bq+r$ for some  $q,r$ because the ring is euclidean, then $a\in (b)$ implies $r=0$ implies $b|a$ !? I'm not sure since there could be many Euclidean functions defined on R. Edit: $a\in(b)$ iff $b|a$ by definition of principal ideal. So we didn't need to use the fact that the ring is Euclidean.

Answer (score 0):

$\impliedby$: Suppose $a=bk$. Let $ x \in (a)$. Then $$x=ta=t(bk)=(tk)b \in (b)$$

$\implies:$ Suppose $(a) \subset (b)$. Then $a \in (b)$ implies $a=bk$, concluding $b|a$